# Destination Charges in Stripe - Trying to set a destination charge but the connect account never receives the amount

Tags: stripe-payments

EDIT: The problem is not that the request failing. It provides a 200 OK response. But the transferred amount never hits the destination account I'm aiming for...

Potentially stupid question here so please be nice.

I'm running some tests via Stripes APIs and I'm trying to POST a destination charge to my account to receive the funds and the connected account to receive the transferred amount.

I've followed the documentation and put together my request as outlined below. However, the transferred amount never reaches the connected stripe account.

What am I doing wrong? I've highlighted my curl request below but I'm using postman for this particular task.

[My postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbypw.png)

```
  -u sk_test_KEY: \
  -d "payment_method_types[]"=card \
  -d amount=2000 \
  -d currency="usd" \
  -d "transfer_data[amount]"="1500"
  -d "transfer_data[destination]"="{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}"
```

Comment: First, you should redact your key immediately. Never post your key (even if it's a Test one) in public place

Comment: Have you confirmed your Stripe API logs (https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs)? If should tell you what's wrong

Comment: @orakaro Thanks re: my key, totally forgot there.

On your second point. The issue is the request is not failing it's returning a 200 Ok response. But the transferred funds are not reaching the destination account.

Comment: You are only creating a payment intent, but it needs to be confirmed and you need a payment method. Likely you're going to want to use Elements to collect card details in the client. For testing, you can add `confirm=true` and `payment_method=pm_card_visa` to your request to see the transfer happen.